# Simplify a logic expression

Tags: digital-logic

I need to simplify the following logic expression:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C & X & SOP \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \overline{A}\ \overline{B}C \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \overline AB\overline C\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \overline ABC \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & A\overline BC\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ABC \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$$X=\overline{A}\ \overline{B}C+\overline AB\overline C+\overline ABC+A\overline BC+ABC$$

I get the following logic expression after simplification:

$$\begin{aligned}X
&=\overline{A}\ \overline{B}C+\overline AB\overline C+\overline ABC+A\overline BC+ABC\\
&=ABC+\overline ABC+\overline{A}\ \overline{B}C+A\overline BC+\overline AB\overline C\\
&=BC(A+\overline A)+\overline BC(A+\overline A)+\overline AB\overline C\\
&=BC+\overline BC+\overline AB\overline C\\
&=C(B+\overline B)+\overline AB\overline C\\
&=C+\overline AB\overline C
\end{aligned}$$

However, K-MAP and Logic Friday each give me a different answer.

Edit: I changed the SOP, there was a mistake.

Comment: Can you post how you get that result?

Comment: Your formula is wrong anyway, it's not just "not simplified enough"

Comment: I posted how I did the simplification. I don't see where I went wrong.

Comment: Whell what you posted now is correct and different from what you posted early

Comment: @user2357111317192329 What did you get after using K-map?

Comment: @VladimirCravero My original SOP logic expression was wrong and I used the wrong SOP to come up with the original simplified logic expression. Thank you for your help.

Comment: \$\overline{AB}\ne\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}\$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how they differ?

Comment: @nidhin you have changed $\overline{AB}$ to $\overline{A}\ \overline{B}$. But this changed the meaning. It's not what was in the original image.

Comment: @Ruslan it's not what was in the original image but it is the correct one. typing `\overline{A}\overline{B}` and `\overline{AB}` will produce indistinguishable result in latex.

Comment: @nidhin How do you know for the OP? What was in the picture is `~(A&B)` (in C-like syntax). What you changed it to is `~A&~B`.

Comment: @Ruslan it appeared like `~(A&B)`. Reading the simplification steps in the original post says that I am correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point where you arrived is almost right:

$$
C+\overline{A}B\overline{C}=C(1+\overline{A}B)+\overline{A}B\overline{C}=\\=
C+\overline{A}BC+\overline{A}B\overline{C}=C+\overline{A}B(C+\overline{C})=\\=
C+\overline{A}B
$$

That should be the same answer the K-map and whatever reduction software should give you.

Comment: @user2357111317192329 yeah, these things just need a TON of practice

Comment: I am still in first year EECS. Do you think I will be doing a lot of those in later years? I find them very interesting for some reason!

Comment: I found them interesting too because of the somewhat different algebra. You won't do much of these, automated tools usually simplify expressions, it will be needed for the exam ofc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting two different answer don't worry

Just make the truth table for both the expressions and compare 
if both give the same answer then you are correct.